# How useful is the sysUptime value in a Netflow packet?

Tags: netflow

The value is in theory precise down to the millisecond, but I am skeptical. 
Does that number tell when the packet was transmitted, or when the connection began or ended?

---

*Note: Subsequently I noticed that there are **flow-start time** & **flow-end time** fields.*

Answer (score 0):

There are both in Netflow v9: according to [rfc3954](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3954.txt):

- section 5.1: sysUptime is the Time in milliseconds since this device was first booted.
- section 8: LAST_SWITCHED and FIRST_SWITCHED sysuptime in msec in which respectively the last/first packet of this flow has been switched.

So you can have both a sysuptime for a flow or the whole device. Looks like your original question is about the header of a Netflow packet, so that would be the uptime of the device.

One last thing: the sysUptime value can only record about 49 days, since it is a 32bit value.

Answer (score -1):

[RFC 5102](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5102) (which is based on Cisco NetFlow Version 9) talks about `flowStartSysUpTime` and `flowEndSysUpTime`. No other sysUptimes.

So, at least, this may be version and/or system dependent.

Comment: I think there is indeed a sysUptime value in NetFlow Version 9 header. You should remove this answer.

Comment: @XavierNicollet, I didn't say that there is no such value in NetFlow Version 9 header. I said that RFC5102-based implementations' headers MAY not contain this value.